# Safari ignores angular animations timing function

Tags: angular, safari, angular-animations

I'm trying to build a animation with angular animations, but if I choose a custom cubic-bezier timing function, it sometimes gets ignored in safari.

Here is my example code of the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qyj9rv

You can see what I mean here:

In Chrome:

> [image: Chrome:]

In Safari:

> [image: Safari]

Comment: Also experiencing this issue in production.

Comment: I'm having this same issue :(, have anyone created an issue on the angular animations github?

Answer (score 1):

@SlateDave my colleague and I have also found this issue while building a toast-like widget using Angular animations. We are on latest Angular 9. Animations work fine in Chrome and Firefox, but the easing in Safari is completely broken and looks terrible. I think it may be wise for us to file this as an Angular animations github issue.

Comment: I thought so too and created this one here a while ago: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/37440